# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to a member function format() on null (View: /home/p4t5z8n7/app-dividendos/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

I had this error message when I tried to made a post without the condiction "Fecha del Aviso".

> ErrorException (E_ERROR) Call to a member function format() on null
>   (View: /home/p4t5z8n7/app-dividendos/resources/views/home.blade.php)

```
<th scope="row">
    Fecha del aviso
</th>
<td>
    <?php echo e($dividendo->fecha_aviso->format('d/m/Y')); ?>
</td>
```

The line 245 is  `<?php echo e($dividendo->fecha_aviso->format('d/m/Y')); ?>`

Anyone knows how can I fix it?

Comment: You need to validate the value is the expected type, Assuming `$dividendo->fecha_aviso` is supposed to be an instance of `DateTimeInterface` or `NULL`, `<?php echo e($dividendo->fecha_aviso instanceof DateTimeInterface ? $dividendo->fecha_aviso->format('d/m/Y') : '');`

Comment: Where is `$dividendo->fecha_aviso` coming from?

Comment: @fyrye it was already like this

Comment: @RenanRibeiro can you try `<?php echo isset($dividendo->fecha_aviso) ? date('d/m/Y', strtotime($dividendo->fecha_aviso)) : 'null' ?>`

Comment: @RenanRibeiro I do not know what you mean, but you are not providing us with info on what data-type `$dividendo->fecha_aviso` is, since it could be a `string`, `unix timestamp`, or `DateTimeInterface`. Please update your question with the Controller that calls `view('app-dividendos/resources/views/home.blade.php', ['dividendo' => $dividendo]);` Chances are `$dividendo` is a failed Database query that is resulting in `NULL` instead of the expected model.

Comment: @AdityaThakur thank you so much, it worked.. your last advice!
#fyrye, thank you so much too. I am sorry but I do not have advanced knowledged in this, I am sorry for that

Comment: So it was null after all, you were correct @fyrye

Comment: @AdityaThakur the error that the value is `null` is in the error message, but no idea where the data is coming from, so we can only guess. Hopefully it is a valid date string, otherwise `strtotime` will return `false`. Since Laravel is capable of returning anything they want from the Eloquent ORM models, which again we don't know if the OP is using them or converting the values from a database in the controller, etc. Guessing the OP is troubleshooting an app that someone else wrote or downloaded package.